# How to initialize two different model class using common base HiveCacheOperation?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
final class HiveCacheManager extends CacheManager {
  /// [path] is the path to the directory
  ///  where the Hive database files are stored.
  HiveCacheManager({super.path});

  @override
  Future<void> init({required List<CacheModel> items}) async {
    final documentPath = path ?? (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    Hive.defaultDirectory = documentPath;

    for (final item in items) {
      Hive.registerAdapter('${item.runtimeType}', item.fromDynamicJson);
    }
  }

  @override
  void remove() {
    Hive.deleteAllBoxesFromDisk();
  }
}
```

```
final class ProductCache {
  ProductCache({required CacheManager cacheManager}) : _cacheManager = cacheManager;

  final CacheManager _cacheManager;

  Future<void> init() async {
    await _cacheManager.init(
      items: [
        UserCacheModel.empty(),
        UserTokenCacheModel.empty(),
      ],
    );
  }

  late final HiveCacheOperation<UserCacheModel> userCacheOperation = HiveCacheOperation<UserCacheModel>();
  late final HiveCacheOperation<UserTokenCacheModel> userTokenCacheOperation =
      HiveCacheOperation<UserTokenCacheModel>();
}
```

Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Type mismatch. Expected UserCacheModel but got UserTokenCacheModel.
E/flutter (11169): #0      _TypeRegistry.fromJson (package:hive/src/impl/type_registry.dart:45:7)
E/flutter (11169): #1      _BoxImpl._frameFromJson (package:hive/src/impl/box_impl.dart:80:31)
E/flutter (11169): #2      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:425:31)
E/flutter (11169): #3      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:354:26)
E/flutter (11169): #4      new _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:189:27)
E/flutter (11169): #5      new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:150:28)
E/flutter (11169): #6      new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:39:18) neden bu hatayı alıyorum

I gonna use two different class model using one common base Hive operation clas.

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct usage.

```
Hive.registerAdapter('${item.runtimeType}', item.fromDynamicJson);
```

The correct usage is =>

```
 Hive.registerAdapter<AdapterClass>(AdapterClass());
```

Comment: Since I am using the new version, this is how I can start the box.

Comment: Contact me here - yilmazrasitt@gmail.com